# What is the maximum byte size for 1 U-Boot environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, u-boot

Odd question, but how big can I make a U-Boot environment variable before it fails?

Essentially what type is a U-boot environment variable?

Answer (score 4):

It depends slightly on what you're doing.  The overall environment is limited to CONFIG_ENV_SIZE.  The amount of text you can input at a given time is CONFIG_SYS_CBSIZE.

Comment: Also relevant: `cmd_nvmedit.c::_do_env_set` and definition of `ENTRY` struct in `search.h`